# Sling Dynamic Include with Dispatcher

Tags: aem

I was looking over the blog [here](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/cq/sling-dynamic-include/) to understand the concept of SDI+Dispatcher. I enable SSI on apache via using this [post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerSideIncludes) & seems it working. But didn't get any material which can demonstrate this concept practically. I am using the same geomatrixx page to where some user logged in and gets cache. How can i store the only static part on the dispatcher cache and how the dynamic component will render at run time. I made changes to my apache conf file as below but now looking over further steps. In blog its also mention to add `<!--#include virtual="/includes/header.html" -->` so where so i need to add this under body.jsp of page component or somewhere on apache server.

```
LoadModule dispatcher_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/dispatcher-apache2.4-4.1.8.so

<IfModule disp_apache2.c>
    <!-- Configurations -->
</IfModule>
 SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
<Directory />

  <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
    SetHandler dispatcher-handler
    ModMimeUsePathInfo On
  </IfModule>
    Options FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride None

</Directory>
```

AND

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sling Dynamic Include automatically replaces components enumerated in the OSGi configuration with the SSI include tag (`<!--#include...`), so you don't have to write this tag in any JSP.

Open the Apache Felix console, go to the *OSGi* / *Configuration* tab and create a new *SDI Configuration* entry. More information on the configuration properties can be found [on the Github](https://github.com/Cognifide/Sling-Dynamic-Include#configuration). Enter resource types of the components and from this moment (assuming that the dispatcher configuration is OK) they will be replaced with SSI include tags and - as a result - served dynamically even if the whole page is cached.

Aforementioned [Github repository](https://github.com/Cognifide/Sling-Dynamic-Include) contains the most up-to-date documentation of the module.

Comment: Thanks Tomek R, I saw the SDI configuration, so means i do not need to configure that component using ssi, like here for me is userinfo. Now I set up two publish instances, Hit the page http://localhost/content/geometrixx/en.html [via dispather], Login with some user say jdoe@geometrixx.info. It doesn't show as loggedin user. Unlike if i hit the publish http://localhost:8589/content/geometrixx/en.html then loggedin via jdoe@geometrixx.info then page show me as loggedin user as i can see the information via userinfo component under header. Any Idea why this is happening.

Comment: Hi @tomek-rękawek , Is that feature working anymore in AEMCaaS . I believe in earlier release of AEMCaaS SSI was disabled at apache side.